# Identity matrix with the diagonals as multiple of the order of the matrix

Tags: python, matrix, identity

How to write a python program to get an identity matrix with the diagonals as the multiple of the order of the matrix. With an option to take input from the user

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

...
n = input("Enter size:")
matrix = n*np.identity(n)
...
```

Comment: Please add explanation so that everyone could understand what this piece of the code does. Many thanks.

Comment: @Reborn please clarify which line requires explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using various ways.

**Using nested for loops**

```py
mat_ord = int(input('Matrix Order: '))

mat = []

for i in range(mat_ord):
    row = []
    for j in range(mat_ord):
        row.append(1) if i == j else row.append(0)
        
    mat.append(row)
    
print(*mat, sep = '\n')
```

**Using list comprehension**

```py
mat_ord = int(input('Matrix Order: '))

mat = [
    [
        1 if i == j else 0 for i in range(mat_ord)
    ]
    for j in range(mat_ord)
]

print(*mat, sep = '\n')
```

I leave it on you with which one you go for. Regarding the multiple, since it's not clear from the question how much you want the multiple to be, just replace `1` with the `x * mat_ord` where `x` is the number of times you want the multiple to be.